# Sequence of arguments in django signals

Tags: django, arguments, signals, sequence, receiver

Below is the receiver function that I wrote.

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):   
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Is there a specific sequence for the arguments in this function?
Can I change the positioning of these arguments?
Eg - def create_profile(sender, created, instance, **kwargs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#post-save), arguments are :

- `sender` : The model class.
- `instance` : The actual instance being saved.
- `created` :  A boolean; True if a new record was created.
- `raw` : A boolean; True if the model is saved exactly as presented (i.e. when loading a fixture). One should not query/modify other records in the database as the database might not be in a consistent state yet.
- `using` : The database alias being used.
- `update_fields` : The set of fields to update as passed to Model.save(), or None if update_fields wasn’t passed to save()

Every argument is sent as a keyword argument, so you can use them in any order as long as you give them a default value.

For instance :

```py
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_profile(raw=True, sender=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    ...
```

You can see how the argument are provided by looking at [where post_save](https://github.com/django/django/blob/225d96533a8e05debd402a2bfe566487cc27d95f/django/db/models/base.py#L778) is sent :

```py
...

# Signal that the save is complete
if not meta.auto_created:
    post_save.send(
        sender=origin, instance=self, created=(not updated),
        update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
    )

...
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me in getting a better clarity.

Comment: @Harshita Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question.